# UWP OnShareTargetActivated Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync does not work after first run

Tags: c#, uwp

I would like to open my app after another app choose my app as the target for sharing a web link.

So first I use OnShareTargetActivated to read the weblink and then use LaunchUriAsync to launch my app through a custom scheme I created for it.

```
protected override async void OnShareTargetActivated(ShareTargetActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        ShareOperation shareOperation = args.ShareOperation;
        try
        {
            if (shareOperation.Data.Contains(StandardDataFormats.WebLink))
            {
                var URL = await shareOperation.Data.GetWebLinkAsync();
                var mAloudURI = @"myApp:?URL=" + URL;
                // Launch the URI
                await Window.Current.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
                {
                    var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(mAloudURI));
                });
                shareOperation.ReportCompleted();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            var i = 0;

        }

    }
```

After that, I use OnActivated to read the link and open my MainPage on the passed link.

```
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.Protocol)
        {
            ProtocolActivatedEventArgs eventArgs = args as ProtocolActivatedEventArgs;

            var url = eventArgs.Uri.PathAndQuery.Substring("?URL=".Length);

            Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
            // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
            // just ensure that the window is active
            if (rootFrame != null)
            {
                rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), url);
            }

        }
    }
```

When I'm debugging I get the expected behavior when I F10 (step through) the line calling LaunchUriAsync, then OnActivated gets executed and MainPage gets displayed with the URL I wanted...
However if I try to share again, the secondary popup window for my app gets displayed for a while and then it disappears. Non of my break points get hit...

Is this the correct approach?

This looks to me like a very logical way of opening other apps with the content you are sharing to them...

Comment: Why you using `Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync` to launch your app again in `OnShareTargetActivated`?  You should just `Navigate` here.

Comment: If I just navigate then the app window is not resizable. I also don't see my ads and I have to dismiss my app window if I would like to continue using the source app.

Comment: So the intention of LaunchUriAsync is to launch my app on a new window independent from the source app.